# database issue with pr2_tabletop_manipulation

Tags: ros, pr2-tabletop-manipulation-apps, pr2, tabletop

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While following [this tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_tabletop_manipulation_apps/Tutorials/Starting%20the%20Manipulation%20Pipeline)  regarding the pr2_tabletop_manipulation_apps package, I run into an error with a database connection. The tutorial further describes how to change the use_database parameter in the launch file so as not to access this database and prevent the error, but this section of the tutorial relies on an older version of the launch file. The current one no longer relies on this parameter, so I am unable to remove this dependence on the database. I have also not been able to find any record of this problem being reported about the updated launch file, so has anyone else experienced this, and does anyone know how to fix it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10413/database-issue-with-pr2_tabletop_manipulation/) by [dlmccoy](https://answers.ros.org/users/726/dlmccoy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-06-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The database connection works fine for me. See Section 5.1 in
[household_objects_databse](http://www.ros.org/wiki/household_objects_database). It should help you well in setting up the database.

---

Originally posted by [vincent](https://answers.ros.org/users/280/vincent/) with karma: 311 on 2011-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0